# Get all children of parent identified by a specific atribute value using xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Is there a way you can get all get all children of a parent with a specific attribute value using xpath, for instance if i wanted to get all the children of the first `<b>` below i could write

```
/a/b[0]/c
```

but is there a way i can do that using a fixed attribute value, something like

```
/a/b=ref:123/c
```

so that i wouldn't matter were in the feed that instance of `<b>` would be

**XML**

```
    <a>
      <b ref="123"></b>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
      <b></b>

      <b ref="456"></b>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
        <c></c>
      <b></b
    </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, with a fixed value like this:

```
/a/b[@ref='123']/c
```